# Cayley's Theorem and group isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G=S_n$, where $n\geq 3.$ Let $H=\{y \in G \mid y(n)=n\}$. Then $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $[G:H] = n$. There is a homomorphism $X: G \rightarrow S_n.$

Show that X is an isomorphism from $G$ to $S_n$.

Since $G = S_n$, isn't this proof trivial? I don't know what I'm supposed to show. We're currently learning about Cayley's theorem and isomorphism theorems in my class, but I don't see how those would help prove that $S_n$ is isomorphic to $S_n$. Is it even necessary to bring up $H$ and kernels and all that business? And if so, how does that prove isomorphism?

Am I missing something here? Is this a trick question?

Comment: Hmm is this coming from a text? Looks like there's a typo. Can you prove that $H$ is isomorphic to $S_{n-1}$?

Comment: Are you sure it is $\;n\le 3\;$ ? Because if it is so then this is boringly simple: just check by hand the cases!

Comment: Woops, that should be greater than or equal to 3.

Comment: You are not being asked to prove that there exists an isomorphism from $S_n$ to $S_n$ (which is obvious), but that a specific homomorphism $X$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: But wouldn't it suffice to say that the homomorphism X is actually an isomorphism because it maps the same group to itself?

Comment: To prove that a homomorphism is an isomorphism, you have to prove that it is a bijection. There do exist homomorphisms from $S_n$ to $S_n$ that are not isomorphisms. You could do it by proving that $X$ has trivial kernel.

Comment: My professor included this exact same problem in my problem set this week. I am confused about the same elements of the problem.. I have written a couple rough drafts of the proof and I keep coming the same dead end (or at least it feels like a dead end to me). Once you have described the Cayley homomorphism from G-->S_x (the symmetric group on the coset space)... I have trouble exhibiting the injective nature of the function (that's all we need to do since Cayley proved that the group operation is preserved... And since G and S_x have the same order... Injectivity implies surjectivity).

Comment: However, I have trouble showing that if phi(g)=phi(g') then g=g' (g in G). I am eager to see this resolved... It's to late to email my professor for help.

Comment: I've tried looking at isomorphism theorems, but I don't see how to prove that X has trivial kernel. Abstract math is too abstract, I am sad.